# Difference in COM Object format between Visio 2008/2010

Tags: visio

I'm maintaining a program which imports Visio diagrams via COM to use them for process simulation. The code looks at the objects in a given diagram and figures out which ones are simulation objects, which ones are arrows connecting simulation objects(showing work flow) and the rest are either blacklisted/discarded or turned into background images which are used to show labels etc.

The code was written before Visio 2010 was released, and starting with that version, when the Visio diagram import code runs, objects are seemingly bound together, with the simulation objects becoming part of the generated background images. Specifically, in the example below, the swimlanes and process steps are embedded into the CFF container. The example diagram I'm using looks like this in Visio:

[image: Visio Diagram]

If I look at just the CFF container in Visio 2010 it looks like this:

[image: CFF Container in Visio]

When imported into the simulation software, if I click and drag the CFF container away, it looks like this:

[image: Imported CFF Container]

The image above is what the full diagram looks like in Visio, when it should look like the second image.

Can anyone advise me on the format changes which occurred in Visio 2010? Can I 'uncouple' the objects I get over COM somehow? I looked for documentation but libvisio from LibreOffice seems to have no documentation at all. And the msdn docs don't mention anything obvious, although I might have missed something.

Answer (score 1):

A reply has been posted on the Visio Guy forum at:
http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=5542.msg22020#msg22020

Comment: Please elaborate your answer

Comment: Yeah I discovered that forum after I posted here. The reply there was very useful, but not a solution.